# Postfix on Ubuntu won't send emails "No such file or directory '/etc/postfix/cacert.pem'"

Tags: php, email, postfix, smtp, smtp-auth

I'm trying to get `postfix` set-up on Ubuntu 13.04 but no luck so far. I found a few answers here on ServerFault that didn't work. I re-installed a bunch of times, nothing. This is my first time dealing with it, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.servermom.com/easy-way-to-install-postfix-on-ubuntu-server/197/) and [this one](http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/installing-phpapc-mysql-postfix-nginx-and-wordpress-on-ubuntu/). I tried [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173742/postfix-server-wordpress), nothing. This is what I get from `telnet localhost 25` and `ehlo localhost`:

```
250-elclanrs.localdomain
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
```

As you can see, no `AUTH` in there...

This is my `main.cf`:

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 192.168.1.0/24 [::1]/128 [fe80::]/64
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/cacert.pem
smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Then I've this in `sasl_passwd`:

```
[smtp.gmail.com]:587 elclanrs@gmail.com:mypass
```

I also configured `php.ini`:

```
sendmail_path = "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"
```

Nothing is working, emails are not being sent from PHP. How to make it work?

Comment: What do your email logs say?

Comment: Didn't think of that... This is my email log from my last attempt https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/fa2b9298d77c9f3a00ff/raw/f14a932698fd67f8187d7915487a8b4955bd2c61/mail.log. Not sure what's going on, any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

(Based on log entries provided in [comment](https://gist.github.com/elclanrs/fa2b9298d77c9f3a00ff/raw/f14a932698fd67f8187d7915487a8b4955bd2c61/mail.log))

```
Apr  9 18:25:41 elclanrs postfix/smtp[13034]: cannot load Certificate Authority data: disabling TLS support
Apr  9 18:25:41 elclanrs postfix/smtp[13034]: warning: TLS library problem: 13034:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:169:fopen('/etc/postfix/cacert.pem','r'):
[...]
Apr  9 18:25:42 elclanrs postfix/smtp[13034]: 249AD3FFAE: to=<elclanrs@elclanrs.spacirdesigns.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.68.109]:587, delay=0.29, delays=0.03/0/0.21/0.04, dsn=5.7.0, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.68.109] said: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. ku2sm27631513qeb.4 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

1. Fix your `smtp_tls_CAfile`
   Check [Postfix: Configuring Gmail as Relay (Ubuntu)](http://mhawthorne.net/posts/postfix-configuring-gmail-as-relay.html)
   It suggests `smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`
2. Gmail offers only SMTP AUTH only over encrypted connections (after STARTTL or over SMTPS).
3. Debian package providing CA data is named ca-certificates

Comment: I'm still trying to solve this. I already have `ca-certificates` installed. What do you mean on point 1? Do I have to install something else? How do I configure Gmail with SSL on postfix?

Comment: Also btw, I tried with "Internet Site" and basically all other options  as well as "Satellite" with Gmail, but I couldn't get none working so far. I'm lost.

Comment: 1) About point 1: Gmail wants STARTTLS before SMTP AUTH. 2) I have added link to a detailed recipe for "gmail relay for postfix". Your smtp_tls_CAfile setting may be wrong.